# Why does the projection matrix not cancel itself out?

Tags: matrices, projection-matrices

For my question you need the definition of the projection matrix:
$Proj = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ and the rule $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$

This leads me to believe the following:

$Proj = X(X'X)^{-1}X' = XX^{-1}X'^{-1}X' = I * I = I$

Surely I must be making a mistake somewhere since this would render the projection matrix useless. I can not see where what I'm missing though since its such a small problem. Can anyone point me to my mistake?

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$?  What does the subscript $j$ indicate?  Is $X$ invertible?

Comment: If $X$ is an invertible square matrix then yes, your $P_j$ is equal to $I$. However, when $X$ is a tall, non-square matrix of full column rank, there is no $X^{-1}$ to work with.

Answer (score 1):

$$(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$$
works only if $A,B$ are both square invertible matrices